# Disabling other buttons on the click of other Button

Tags: android, android-button

In my application , i have 3 buttons A,B,C . on the press of button A, i am doing some computations that takes some time ... in that period , i want to disable the other two buttons. I am providing the code for the onClick listener for one button..

```
case R.id.buttona:

    //Disabling other two buttons
    start1b.setVisibility(v.INVISIBLE);
    start1c.setVisibility(v.INVISIBLE);
    stop1.setVisibility(v.INVISIBLE);

        //this is the process that takes time 
    String x ="/databank/Reading18.wav";
    timedata1a = fe.returningtimedata(x);

    rawdata1a = fe.returningrawdata(x); 
    Log.d("now press", "button");

    //features of Reading 1 hav been extracted into timedata1a 
    start1b.setVisibility(v.VISIBLE);
    start1c.setVisibility(v.VISIBLE);
    stop1.setVisibility(v.VISIBLE);

break;
```

but when i press 1 button A and then immediately press button B , the application force closes .. can any1 help ??

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful, wonderful world of threading! You will want to put all time-consuming processes in their own threads. This will allow you to immediately disable the buttons, eliminating your fatal exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to perform operations which you want to perform in disabled state in other thread than UI. cause event thread never gets time to disable the buttons. so You can do following:

```
case R.id.buttona:

    //Disabling other two buttons
    start1b.setVisibility(v.INVISIBLE);
    start1c.setVisibility(v.INVISIBLE);
    stop1.setVisibility(v.INVISIBLE);

     Thread thread=new Thread()
     {
        public void run()
        {

                 //this is the process that takes time 
                  String x ="/databank/Reading18.wav";
                  timedata1a = fe.returningtimedata(x);

                 rawdata1a = fe.returningrawdata(x); 
                 Log.d("now press", "button");
                 handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);



          }
       }
       thread.start();
       break;
    }
```

You need to define a handler to post results back to UI thread after thread processiing completes.

```
Handler handler=new Handler();
{
    public void handleMessage(Message msg)
    {
         int what=msg.what;
         switch(what)
         { 
            case 1:
                  {
                       //features of Reading 1 hav been extracted into timedata1a 
                     start1b.setVisibility(v.VISIBLE);
                     start1c.setVisibility(v.VISIBLE);
                     stop1.setVisibility(v.VISIBLE);
                  }
                  break;
             .........
         }
    }
};
```

Comment: can u plz specify where should i define the handleMessage function>>

Answer (score 0):

In your case if you want to disable Buttons B,C when you perform onClick() operation on Button A

```
btnA.setOnClickListerner(new OnClickListerner() {

public void onClick(){

btnB.setEnabled(false);

btnC.setEnabled(false);

}  

});
```

In the above code when you click on Button A The Button B,C get Disabled.

Comment: this is not working .. srikanth .. the buttons donot get disabled.. plz specify